# Null encountered when deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have json message

```
{"code":200,
"description":{
 "15":{"id":"15","name":"US"},
 "25":{"id":"25","name":"Canada"},
 "msg":"Ok"}}
```

I am trying to deserialize it with such classes

```
public class NewCountry
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class NewCountryDescription
{
    public List<NewCountry> Countries{ get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public NewCountryDescription description { get; set; }
}

var ListOfCountries = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(res);
```

But I am always getting null at `NewCountry` what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your JSON has invalid C# class names. You probably want to use valid ones so you can deserialize more easily.

Comment: In addition to what Yuval is saying, you are using a list (collection) of countries, but the JSON is explicitly returning 2, not a collection, so your class definition doesn't really match the JSON.

Comment: Do you have to have msg in description?

Comment: Not it's not important to have msg in description.

Comment: Is it possible to deserialize 2 object to the list of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove msg from your json or move it somewhere else (not in the descrition), it will work:

```
    {"code":200,
"description":{
 "15":{"id":"15","name":"US"},
 "25":{"id":"25","name":"Canada"}
 }}


    public class RootObject
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, NewCountry> description { get; set; }
    }

    public class NewCountry
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You doesn't have parsable collection, so you can use JObject and dynamic or key/value access.

```
        var result = JObject.Parse(res);
        var description = (result["description"] as JObject);

        if (description != null)
        {
            var root = new RootObject
            {
                code = (int)result["code"],
                description = new NewCountryDescription
                {
                    msg = description["msg"].ToString(),
                    Countries = (from prop in description.Properties()
                                 where prop.Name != "msg"
                                 select new NewCountry
                                 {
                                     id = prop.Value["id"].ToString(),
                                     name = prop.Value["name"].ToString()
                                 }).ToList()
                }
            };

            Console.Write(root);
        }
```